# Only one command line in PROJ.4

Tags: proj

I would like to know if there are a way to write only one command line to obtain the expected results. I explain:

When you write this :

### $ proj +proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=WGS84 -f %12.6f

If you want to recieved the output data:

### 500000.000000 4427757.218739

You must to write in another line with the input data:

### -105 40

Is it possible to write concatenated command line as this stile?:

### $ proj +proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=WGS84 -f %12.6f | -105 40

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and found the solution:

```
echo -105 40 | proj +proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=WGS84 -f %12.6f
```

That should do the trick.

If you need to do this e.g. from within c#, the command you'd use is this:

```
cmd.exe /c echo -105 40 | proj +proj=utm +zone=13 +ellps=WGS84 -f %12.6f
```

Note: you may need to double up the `%` as the command processor interprets this as a variable.